# PostgreSQL - Determining the Percentage of a Total

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin, psql

I have a table

```
ID    |    NUMBER
------|----------
1     |      102
2     |      145
3     |      512
4     |      231
5     |       94
```

and I want to sum all 'NUMBER' and return a % value from total to each row.
Result should look like this:

```
ID    |    NUMBER    |   PERC
------|--------------|-------
1     |      102     |   9.4
2     |      145     |  13.4
3     |      512     |  47.2
4     |      231     |  21.3
5     |       94     |   8.7
```

So far, I have something like:

```
SELECT (number/sum(number)*100) AS perc
FROM mytable;
```

but as you know for sure, that 'number' must appear in GROUP BY or aggregate function so I can't use it.  How to do that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use `sum` with an `over` clause:

```
SELECT  100.0 * number / sum(number) over () as perc
FROM    mytable;
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/e7be8/4/0)

Comment: You might like to protect that against division-by-zero errors?